# Many to many join behaviour

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Not really sure how to title this question, but here's the situation. I have one data frame (dfOrders) that has an order_id and basic information like so:

```
|order_id|full_name|order_date|billing|shipping|
------------------------------------------------
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address1|
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address2|
```

Then there's a second data frame (dfStandardized) that contains standardized address information:

```
|order_id|latitude |longitude |shippingZip|...
-------------------------------------------
|1234567 |97.12345 |101.1245  |12345      |...
|1234567 |98.98765 |102.9876  |12389      |...
```

And essentially the issue is that one customer placed one order but shipped it to two separate addresses. Because of this, there is only one order_id but two rows, one for each of the shipping addresses. What I would like is a data frame like so:

```
|order_id|full_name|order_date|billing|shipping|latitude |longitude |shippingZip|...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address1|97.12345 |101.1245  |12345      |...
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address2|98.98765 |102.9876  |12389      |...
```

Where the extra shipping info is only added to the row with the corresponding correct address, but what I'm getting is:

```
|order_id|full_name|order_date|billing|shipping|latitude |longitude |shippingZip|...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address1|97.12345 |101.1245  |12345      |...
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address2|98.98765 |102.9876  |12389      |...
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address1|98.98765 |102.9876  |12389      |...
|1234567 |John Doe |1/1/2019  |Address|Address2|97.12345 |101.1245  |12345      |...
```

Where both addresses are getting receiving the supplemental attribution of both addresses. This is obviously because it's a many-to-many join due to only having one order_id. is there some way to get the result I want? Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = dfOrders.merge(dfStandardized, on = 'order_id', how = 'inner')
```

Comment: Without a way to verify that Address1 should go with (97.12345, 101.1245) and not the other observation it's unlikely you're going to join the correct rows. Unless you can ensure the observations in each are in ordered, but from the look it might be sorted on zip, lat, or longitude, all of which make this impossible.

Comment: that's kinda the conclusion I've come to. trying to filter rows after joining doesn't seem to be reproducible due to variation in the addresses

Comment: Well is there any hope that the first row for the same `order_id` in dfOrders should be joined with the first row for that same `order_id` in dfStandardized? If some system logged them, ideally the order would be maintained like that. If so you would create a new column in each using `df['idx'] = df.groupby('order_id').cumcount()` and then you could merge `on=['order_id', 'idx']`

Comment: Do the addresses contain the zip codes?  In that case, you would at least be able to disambiguate orders sent to different zips.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they do, however there are instances where the zip codes for each address don't differ.

Comment: @ALollz unfortunately the order is not preserved so using the index to join isn't viable

Comment: You could use some geo packages to look up longitude and latitude from address and match on them.

Comment: You could query google maps api, but it is expensive. For each lat long you will get a zip code

Comment: @keiv.fly that's a bit too involved for what we're looking for, but it was considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we do `cumcount`

```
dfOrders['New']=dfOrders.groupby('order_id').cumcount()
dfStandardized['New']=dfStandardized.groupby('order_id').cumcount()
out=dfOrders.merge(dfStandardized, on = ['order_id','new'], how = 'inner').drop('New',1)
```